# Change style programmatically ionic toast

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, sass

I have the following ionicToast into my popup:

```
onTap: function(e) {
                    var nombre = scope.data.nombre;
                    var telefono = scope.data.telefono;
                    if (nombre.length > 0 && telefono.toString().length > 0) {
                        scope.data.nombre = nombre;
                        scope.data.telefono = telefono;
                        return scope.data;
                    } else {
                        ionicToast.show('Debe completar todos los campos.', 'bottom', true, 2500);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
```

The toast works perfect. But I wanna differentiate when the toast is an error or a success message.

The question is: **¿How can I change the style of the toast programmatically?** 
Because Sometimes I need the background red (for error message) and sometimes i need it green (for success message).

Also I don't have this toast in my .HTML file, so I can't set a specific style

This is my style that I defined:

```
.toast-container-error{
    background-color: red;
}

.toast-container-success{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

**//EDIT//**
Using toastr for my custom toast, it not showing on Android devices

**index.html**

```
<link href="bower_components/toastr/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Agenda.service** (where I wanna use it)

```
agendaService.$inject = ['remoteDataService','$q', '$ionicPopup', '$rootScope', 'ionicDatePicker'];

/* @ngInject */
function agendaService(remoteDataService,$q, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, ionicDatePicker){ 
    var agendaComplejo = [];
    var service = {
        obtenerAgenda: obtenerAgenda,
        cargarNuevoTurno: cargarNuevoTurno,
        abrirAgenda: abrirAgenda
    };
    toastr.options = {
          "closeButton": true,
          "debug": true,
          "newestOnTop": false,
          "progressBar": false,
          "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width",
          "preventDuplicates": false,
          "onclick": null,
          "showDuration": "300",
          "hideDuration": "1000",
          "timeOut": "5000",
          "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
          "showEasing": "swing",
          "hideEasing": "linear",
          "showMethod": "fadeIn",
          "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
    return service;

function cargarNuevoTurnoPopup() {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.data = {
            nombre: '',
            telefono: ''
        };
        return {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/complejo/agenda/nuevo-turno.html',
            title: "Nuevo Turno",
            scope: scope,
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Cancelar',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    scope.data.canceled = true;
                    return scope.data;
                }
            }, {
                text: '<b>Guardar</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    var nombre = scope.data.nombre;
                    var telefono = scope.data.telefono;
                    if (nombre.length > 0 && telefono.toString().length > 0) {
                        scope.data.nombre = nombre;
                        scope.data.telefono = telefono;
                        return scope.data;
                    } else {
                        toastr["error"]("Debe completar todos los campos.")
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }]
        };
    }
```

Also, I generate the apk with the following command:

```
ionic build android --debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you have to overide the native style of the component to do this. In our project we use Toastr that give you standard method to display an error or an info and that can be overide more easily.

To include it in your project only include the js and the css

```
<script src="toastr.js"></script>
<link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Then the api allow you to raise an info or an error

```
toastr.info('yourmessage')
toastr.error('your message')
toastr.success('your message')
```

You can found a demo here:
http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: I installed toastr. with grunt serve --lab works perfect, but when I make a debug apk not working the toastr with my android. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: ok the toast does not appear ? how do you install your toastr module? how do you generate the apk?

Comment: Please see my edit post. This si how I installed my toastr module.